# Parenthesis in npm script

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I use the following shell command to activate my prompt. Works fine from the shell.

```
source <(curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jbnv/78ce47382faf454553ef/raw/4382bf0a2ac3742dfd777e34fbb14b16b0f3d06b/prompt.sh)
```

I put this into an NPM script so that I could share it among multiple projects and not have to type it out entirely:

```
"scripts": {
    "prompt": "source <(curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jbnv/78ce47382faf454553ef/raw/4382bf0a2ac3742dfd777e34fbb14b16b0f3d06b/prompt.sh)"
},
```

When I `npm run script`, it throws `sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Npm utilizes `sh` as the default shell for executing npm scripts - not `bash`. Process substitution, i.e. `<()`, is not supported by `sh`, as mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309547/what-is-the-portable-posix-way-to-achieve-process-substitution). Either try; **A)** Pass your script as a string to `bash -c`, E.g. Define your npm script as; `"prompt": "bash -c \"source <(curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jbnv/78ce47382faf454553ef/raw/4382bf0a2ac3742dfd777e34fbb14b16b0f3d06b/prompt.sh)\""`

Comment: **B)** Or try using the [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) command to change the [script-shell](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#script-shell) setting to `bash` instead. You can run `which bash` to obtain the path to bash, then run something like; `npm config set script-shell "/bin/bash"` - whereby the `/bin/bash` part in the aforementioned example should be substituted with the path returned from `which bash`

Comment: Neither A nor B work, and it looks like the reason why is that NPM runs the command in its own shell. So the prompt gets changed in a shell that goes away after the command. If this is the case then there is no solution because the command will never work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

So try this as referenced in the picture

```
"prompt": "source '<(curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jbnv/78ce47382faf454553ef/raw/4382bf0a2ac3742dfd777e34fbb14b16b0f3d06b/prompt.sh)'"
```

[image]

Comment: `sh: 1: source: not found`